# Outputting file always empty since struct function introduced?

Tags: c#, arrays, struct

had my code working, but the mix of double and strings i need to work with pushed me towards using Struct in my code, however i keep getting an empty results file, and i cant see why... it will no doubt be obvious to everyone else :/ any assistance greatly appreciated,,,,,

SB

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    public struct RArray
    {
        public string ChNum;
        public string StartDate;
        public double IQuies;
        public double ISample;
        public double IWriteTX;
        public double IDepass;
        public double IDischarge;
        public string DischargeDateCompleted;



    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string[,] TestLoads = new string[16, 8]    

                                                            //Enable, RQuies,   RSample, RWriteTx,   RDepass, RDischarge, DischargeDate, Discharge Time
                                                           {{  "1",  "232000",  "3770",  "100000000" , "191" ,  "1180" ,  "2008-12-23",  "12:00:00" },//0 3
                                                            {  "1",  "232000",  "3770",  "100000000" , "191" ,  "1180" ,  "2009-04-03",  "16:32:00" },//1 3
                                                            {  "1",  "232000",  "3770",  "100000000" , "191" ,  "1180" ,  "2009-04-03",  "16:32:00" },//2 6
                                                            {  "1",  "232000",  "3770",  "100000000" , "191" ,  "1180" ,  "2009-04-03",  "16:32:00" },//3 6
                                                            {  "1",  "475000",  "7560",  "100000000" , "383" ,  "1180" ,  "2009-04-03",  "16:32:00" },//4 csc93 12
                                                            {  "1",  "475000",  "7560",  "100000000" , "383" ,  "1180" ,  "2009-04-03",  "16:32:00" },//5 csc93 12
                                                            {  "1",  "232000",  "3770",  "100000000" , "191" ,  "1180" ,  "2009-04-03",  "16:32:00" },//6 12
                                                            {  "1",  "232000",  "3770",  "100000000" , "191" ,  "1180" ,  "2009-04-03",  "16:32:00" },//7 12
                                                            {  "1",  "232000",  "3770",  "100000000" , "191" ,  "1180" ,  "2009-04-03",  "16:32:00" },//8 12
                                                            {  "1",  "232000",  "3770",  "100000000" , "191" ,  "1180" ,  "2009-04-03",  "16:32:00" },//9 12 
                                                            {  "1",  "232000",  "3770",  "100000000" , "191" ,  "1180" ,  "2009-04-03",  "16:32:00" },//10 continuing
                                                            {  "1",  "232000",  "3770",  "100000000" , "191" ,  "1180" ,  "2009-04-03",  "16:32:00" },//11 na
                                                            {  "1",  "475000",  "7560",  "100000000" , "383" ,  "1180" ,  "2009-04-03",  "16:32:00" },//12 csc93 24
                                                            {  "1",  "475000",  "7560",  "100000000" , "383" ,  "1180" ,  "2009-04-03",  "16:32:00" },//13 csc93 24
                                                            {  "1",  "232000",  "3770",  "100000000" , "191" ,  "1180" ,  "2009-04-03",  "16:32:00" },//14 24
                                                            {  "1",  "232000",  "3770",  "100000000" , "191" ,  "1180" ,  "2009-04-03",  "16:32:00" }};//15 24

        int[,] FileMap = new int[16, 5]    

                                                           //Vtop index, Results Row, Sample index, WriteTX index, Depass Index, ]
                                                           {{9 , 0, 41, 42, 73},
                                                            {10, 1, 43, 44, 74},
                                                            {11, 2, 45, 46, 75},
                                                            {12, 3, 47, 48, 76},
                                                            {13, 4, 49, 50, 77,},
                                                            {14, 5, 51, 52, 78,},
                                                            {15, 6, 53, 54, 79,},
                                                            {16, 7, 55, 56, 80,},
                                                            {25, 8, 57, 58, 81,},
                                                            {26, 9, 59, 60, 82,},
                                                            {27,10, 61, 62, 83,},
                                                            {28,11, 63, 64, 84,},
                                                            {29,12, 65, 66, 85,},
                                                            {30,13, 67, 68, 86,},
                                                            {31,14, 69, 70, 87,},
                                                            {32,15, 71, 72, 88,}};



        double Vtop;
        //double IQuies;
        double RQuies;
        //double ISample;
        double RSample;
        //double IWriteTX;
        double RWriteTx;
        //double IDepass;
        double RDepass;
        //double IDischarge;
        double RDischarge;
        double WriteTXIndicator;
        double SampleIndicator;
        double DepassIndicator;
        int[] DischargeStatusFlag = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        string DischargeDateTime;
        //string DischargeDateCompleted;


        RArray[] ScratchResults = new RArray[16];





        var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:\Users\SBoyle\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\1Day Test File\00 Dev1 2008-12-23 08-47-48.csv")); // Static for testing only, to be replaced by file filter code

        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Test started on {0}", (DateTime.Now));
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();



        reader.ReadLine(); // skip headers, read and do nothing
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {


            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            var values = line.Split(',');



            for (int Row = 0; Row < 16; Row++)
            {



                SampleIndicator = Convert.ToSingle(values[FileMap[Row, 2]]); // Mapping for Sample indicator
                DepassIndicator = Convert.ToSingle(values[FileMap[Row, 4]]);
                WriteTXIndicator = Convert.ToSingle(values[FileMap[Row, 3]]);

                RQuies = Convert.ToDouble(TestLoads[Row, 1]);
                RSample = Convert.ToDouble(TestLoads[Row, 2]);
                RWriteTx = Convert.ToDouble(TestLoads[Row, 3]);
                RDepass = Convert.ToDouble(TestLoads[Row, 4]);
                RDischarge = Convert.ToDouble(TestLoads[Row, 5]);

                DischargeDateTime = (values[0]);

                Vtop = Convert.ToSingle(values[FileMap[Row, 0]]);

                //if (DischargeStatusFlag[(Row)] == 0)
                //{

                // if (Vtop < 5.4)
                //  {

                //      DischargeStatusFlag[Row] = 1;
                //       Console.WriteLine("Channel Number {0} was less than 5.4v on {1},", (Row), DischargeDateTime);

                //   }
                //

                //IQuies = (Vtop / RQuies);          //Quiesecent load is in ohms, but summing V0,[09] x 32000 at this point for debugging
                ScratchResults[Row]. += (Vtop / RQuies);  //Add IQuiescent to ScratchResults Quiescent location containing previous IQuies value artefact


                if (SampleIndicator == 1)
                {
                    //Add ISample to ScratchResults Sample location containing previous ISample value artefact
                    ScratchResults[Row].ISample += (Vtop / RSample);
                }



                if (DepassIndicator == 1)
                {
                    //Add IDepass to ScratchResults Depass location containing previous IDepass value artefact
                    ScratchResults[Row].IDepass += (Vtop / RDepass);
                }



                if (WriteTXIndicator == 1)
                {
                    //Add IWriteTX to ScratchResults WriteTX location containing previous IWriteTX value artefact

                    ScratchResults[Row].IWriteTX += (Vtop / RWriteTx);
                }

                //}

            }
        }

            Console.WriteLine(ScratchResults[0].IQuies);

            using (StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter(@"C:\\ScratchResultsContent.txt"))
            {
                outfile.WriteLine("BatteryCell nnDevn Channel# ,nnDevn Start Date ,nnDevn Quiescent Total Coulombs ,nnDevn Sample Total Coulombs, nnDevn WriteTX Total Coulombs ,nnDevn Depass Total Coulombs ,nnDevn Discharge date start , nnDevn Discharge Date Completed (VTop<5.4volts), nnDevn Discharge Total Coulombs, nnDevn Cell/Battery delivered Total Coloumbs");
                for (int x = 0; x < 16; x++)
                {
                    string content = "";
                    for (int y = 0; y < 1; y++)
                    {

                        content = ScratchResults[x].ChNum ;
                        content = ScratchResults[x].StartDate ;
                        content += ScratchResults[x].IQuies.ToString();
                        content += ScratchResults[x].ISample.ToString();
                        content += ScratchResults[x].IWriteTX.ToString();
                        content += ScratchResults[x].IDepass.ToString();
                        content = ScratchResults[x].DischargeDateCompleted;
                        content += ScratchResults[x].IDischarge.ToString();


                    }
                }
            }

        Console.WriteLine("Test ended on {0}", (DateTime.Now));
        Console.ReadLine();




    }

    }
```

Comment: Does it contain one line, starting with "BatteryCell nnDevn Channel# ,nn..." ?

Comment: Because you never write the content out!

Comment: L@LasseV.Karlsen yes it is the header file, had typo on exit routine, fixed that, but doesnt change the issue of no output,,, @Lukos

Comment: ...and even when you fix this, you've overwritten the value of `content` a number of times, rendering much of the code in the loop that generates `content` redundant.

Comment: Ok, can you point to the line of code actually writing data to that file?

Comment: What are you expecting in the file after the Header line?

Comment: "but the mix of double and strings i need to work with pushed me towards using Struct in my code". Can you justify this? I don't see this as a logical sequitur.

Comment: It would really help if you'd give a *short* but complete program, nicely formatted without *enormous* amounts of whitespace, which demonstrates the problem. (I very much doubt that you need that many fields in order to demonstrate the problem.) I'd also *strongly* recommend against: a) creating structs that large; b) exposing public fields; c) creating mutable structs.

Comment: i am a muppet! thank you @Lukos ! the addition of outfile.WriteLine(content) helps, funny that :)

Comment: and as spender says, you are using a mixture of += and = to join your strings, which won't work! If you are going to need spaces or commas or something between the values, use String.Format or a StringBuilder instead, otherwise you are asking for bugs.

Comment: no fix, thanks to all for reply, i must have deleted the output while i was trying things, @Lukos , i expect to find ChNum, IQuies, etc all in a row, and 16 rows of similar data in total,

Comment: fix found, @Lukos set me in right direction, so change output to manage the string conversion better, code below, thanks all for replying, your advice is priceless in my learning curve,,,     content = Convert.ToString(ScratchResults[x].IQuies);

Comment: i take it back, looks like it doesnt work with more than one item in the for loop, so Stringbuilder it is,,,